# How to get certificate file from server?

Tags: node.js, sockets

When i dont get any proper answer so i asked this question that i created a chat app for my site using socket.io and node.js my site is on https server it's not working it's giving me error

GET https://example.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1507034613131-2 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

**CODE IS HERE**

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var forceSsl = require('express-force-ssl');

app.use(forceSsl);

var options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};


var server = require('https').createServer(options, app).listen(3000,function(){
        console.log("Https server started on port 3000");
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

i find above code for https authentication so how can i get these files i have already installed ssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can check in your cpanel there is ssl manager which is cpanel service so you can get from there after that you can use in your https nodejs service